# what part of MERN stack app should be tested?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, mern

I got simple MERN stack app with form in react, which passes fields to redux state. Redux connects with node/express on backend which saved data in MongoDB.

Form need to contain valid email (which is checked in react).

My task is to test app, but I'm not sure what I can test and which tools I can use to accomplish this task.

My first idea is to test react component function that validates email and another one that check date format.

Answer (score 1):

For frontend (ReactJS) testing purposes you can use `JEST` testing framework for testing https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-react

With this tool you will be able to test what you want on frontend side.

For testing backend (Node.js) you can see `Mocha` https://github.com/mochajs/mocha, but you should be able to test Node app with `JEST` as well.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Could I ask what part of this simple app would you test? And yes, that helps me a lot, thanks!

Comment: Of course, if you are to test frontend, then definitely test all validations on frontend. As for backend, test that all data gets persisted and that logic is taking in account any potential errors and exceptions. If this answer answers your question please accept it for future reference.

Comment: Thank you Sir! This will help me greatly!